# Multiple Namespaces in one C# UWP App for Raspberry Pi 3 IOT

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, iot

I am using a raspberry Pi 3 that's running Windows 10 IOT Core. I'm trying to create a UWP app and already have several project files with different parts of the code running. I have one project file to run my heater and motor, a different one to collect data from a Thermistor, and another one to write a text file from the data. They are all compiling and running on their own. I want to combine all of these into one project and (from what I understand about processes/threads) multiple processes since I want them all to run simultaneously. Is there a way to do this? I have the Thermistor running as a Startup background task and both the other projects right now are running as a Main. Is there a way to combine these three project files (even just by copying and pasting into a new project file)? I also need the Thermistor project to send data to the text file project. Sorry if this is a stupid question...I'm new at all this and really appreciate any/all help/advice!

Comment: The answer to your question differs greatly dependent on "Do you want all 3 of the _projects_ you've listed to run as separate processes, or should it be a single process?" To help you answer that (you'll probably want to update your question accordingly), maybe [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx) will help explain?

Comment: @Smudge202 thank you for your response and for the article. I had actually read about threads/processes but wasn't sure if I was on the right track. My feeling is that I should have the 3 projects run as separate processes since they all need to be executing at the same time. From the way I understand it, If I put them all in one process, then they would be different threads and only one thread can run at a time.

Comment: You can only execute 1 thread per CPU core at a time. But, operating systems are constantly scheduling the threads so that they can execute a little bit at a time, balancing out the CPU time for the threads. The same is true whether you split those processes or you share them. I'd recommend using a single process (for simplicity) but it means you are going to need to research how to run a multi-threaded application (plenty of tutorials on google). Fortunately, it sounds like you don't need thread synchronization from what you've described, which makes it a lot easier. Good luck!